# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 947 and input n_features is 15

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So, i'm using random forest to this dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/auto+mpg 
But when I try to predict something, it throws this error:

> ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 947 and input n_features is 15

this is my files:

```py
import joblib  # para salvar o modelo
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  # Para Normalizar
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

data = pd.read_csv('auto-mpg.csv',sep = ',')

data['horsepower'] = data['horsepower'].replace('?','100')

x = data.iloc[:,1:].values
y = data.iloc[:,0].values

lb = LabelEncoder()
x[:,7] = lb.fit_transform(x[:,7])

onehot = OneHotEncoder()
x = onehot.fit_transform(x).toarray()

xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2,random_state = 0)

sc = StandardScaler()
x = sc.fit_transform(x)

rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 200,random_state = 0)
rfr.fit(xtrain,ytrain)

ypred_rfr = rfr.predict(xtest)
print('Acuracia:',round(r2_score(ytest,ypred_rfr)*100,2),'%')

joblib.dump(rfr,'randon-forest.model')
```

and here it goes to error:

```py
import joblib  # para salvar o modelo
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data = pd.read_csv('teste.csv',sep = ',')
print(data.columns);
logit = joblib.load('randon-forest.model')

onehot = OneHotEncoder()
data = onehot.fit_transform(data).toarray()

sc = StandardScaler()
data = sc.fit_transform(data)

# montar um vetor de dados
dados_vet = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)
# classificar esse vetor com o logit_bank
result_predict = logit.predict(dados_vet)

print('Logit Bank')
print(result_predict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR:
The data which is used for prediction must have the same number of features as the data which was used to train the model.

A more detailed answer:
You train the model on `auto-mpg.csv`, which I guess has 947 features (columns) in it (+1 column as the tagging value). However, the data at `teste.csv`, which I don't know what it is, probably has only 15 features in it, hence you cannot predict a 15 features data using a model which was trained on a different number of features.

A simple example: let's say you have a model that predicts the house price given the year the house was built and the number of rooms using this formula:

```
price = number_of_rooms * 5 + (year-2000) * 20
```

What you are trying to do with your code, is the equivalent of providing this example model only the number of rooms. The model has to 'know' the year as well.

Comment: how the it will be equal ? In the second file I put 2 lines just to test

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the it will be equal"? what is "it"?
Each line in the new file (for prediction) has to consist the same number of features (947) as used in the training samples. Since it's a CSV file, you need something along:  
(line 1) "1,2,3,4,5,...,946,947"  
(line 2) "1001,1002,...,1946,1947"  
Repeated for 947 values in each line.

Comment: no, in both files the data are organized with 9 columns. is the same thing, the only difference is that in one I have multiple registers (to train) and in the other I have only 2

Comment: OK. So the flow you use to process the training data is not the same as the flow for the data you use for prediction. I'm not very familiar with `LabelEncoder`, but seems like the data goes through it during training and not during pre-prediction. My suggestion is to debug your code using `x.shape[1]` and `data.shape[1]` to see in what stage the shapes separate.

Comment: Another issue: you have to be careful when using [fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.fit_transform) methods during your prediction stage, since it both fits the transformer to the predicition data, and transforms the data. It might be OK, but for example you fit a new scaler using the prediction data- you (usually) should use the fitted scaler from the training stage. Not sure about the `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder`, but I suspect more care should be considered with them too.