# Updated : np.arange(min(indp),max(indp),0.01) ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, regression, random-forest

I have a random forest regressor for crop yield prediction with 5 relevant features to the regressor `['Precipitation'    ,'Min_Temp' ,'Cloud_Cover'  ,'Vapour_pressure'  ,'Area']` and my dependent variable is `Production` for the given dataset this code is giving me the following error

```
 x_grid = np.arange(min(indp),max(indp),0.01)
 ValueError :  The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

code :

```
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import reshape
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor


df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')



X = df[['Precipitation' ,'Min_Temp' ,'Cloud_Cover'  ,'Vapour_pressure'  ,'Area']] 
Y = df['Production']
 

def Preprocessing(df,drop_indx_list):
    for indx in  drop_indx_list:
        df=df.drop(indx)
        df.reset_index()
    df.loc[df.Min_Temp>40,'Min_Temp']=df.Min_Temp.mean()
    return df

def DataVisualization(chart_list):
    colors = ['blue','red','green','black','yellow']
    c = 0
    for chrt in chart_list:
        t1,x,t2 = chrt.split()
        plt.scatter(df[t1],df[t2],color=colors[c])
        plt.title(chrt)
        plt.xlabel(t1)
        plt.ylabel(t2)
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
        c+=1

drop_indx_list = [4]
df =  Preprocessing(df,drop_indx_list)
viusal_list = ['Precipitation Vs Production','Min_Temp Vs Production','Cloud_Cover Vs Production',
'Vapour_pressure  Vs Production','Area Vs Production']

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_train,y_train)
  




# prediction
y_pred=reg.predict(x_test)
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    print('data point number : ',i," prediction : ",y_pred[i],'\n')

# Coefficients
print('\nCoefficients: ', reg.coef_,'\n')

# R-squared score
print('\nR-squared score: ', r2_score(y_test,y_pred),'\n')

# DataVisualization(viusal_list)

# Random forest
indp = df.iloc[:,1:6].values



dep = df.iloc[:,6].values

reg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10,random_state=0)
reg.fit(indp,dep)
y_pred_reg = reg.predict(indp) #fix1

x_grid = np.arange(min(indp),max(indp),0.01) # current error
x_grid = x_grid.reshape((len(x_grid),1))
plt.scatter(indp,dep,color = 'red')
plt.plot(x_grid,reg.predict(x_grid),color ='blue')
plt.title('Random forest regression')
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Prodution')
```

Dataset :

```
Dist,Precipitation,Min_Temp,Cloud_Cover,Vapour_pressure,Area,Production
Bidar,622.438,27.643,35.241,17.953,4709,9043
Bangalore,748.194,25.263,49.134,21.56,18790,20981
Belgaum,1334.194,21.254,39.728,22.5509,4398,6054
Bellary,574.325,26.407,38.466,20.008,3768,5903
Bengalore Rural,733.003,25.228000,47.620000,21.241000,140213,534214
Kolar,724.545,25.464,47.029,20.63,2278,2759
Dharwad,1623.548,26.148,38.267,23.652,8395,10986
Koppal,724.545,26.871005,41.039,19.992,3084,3952
Chikmagalur,1923.742,26.459,44.842,24.717,1650,2958
Chitradurga,674.17,25.214,41.364,20.82,3026,3325
Haveri,1473.343,25.817,41.292,23.168,10659,9865
Chamrajanagar,1334.754,25.089,50.77,23.079,3485,4120
Mandya,1477.249,24.567,49.54775,22.234,11349,18957
Mysore,2242.378,25.76766667,50.57941667,24.64266667,3462,4539
Raichur,450.113,27.42241667,35.76258333,18.93741667,4586,6145
Kodaku,1691.933,25.426,46.353,23.975,17856,15362
Hassan,2200.349,25.348,47.12,24.008,10487,7586
Devanagare,1060.343,25.509,40.929,22.042,2459,1865
Gulbarga,525.402,27.851,35.109,18.662,10487,7895
```

I tried this one but it didn't help [Similar Query link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937630/valueerror-number-of-features-of-the-model-must-match-the-input-model-n-featur)

edit : reg.predict(indp) correction instead of [[6.5]]

but now the line  `np.arange(min(indp),max(indp),0.01)` gives me another error the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: It means that you have trained a model with 5 features and u are giving it as input for later prediction only one feature. Actually your issue is at `y_pred_reg = reg.predict([[6.5]])`. Note that you are passing to the trained model an array with a single value. You need to give to the model 5 features.

Comment: @KostisPar after this one being resolved another one has popped up.

Comment: The `indp` object is something like `[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]]` And you are telling python to find the minimum of it through `min(indp)`, which is not possible. `min` expects an array not an array of arrays if you want the actual minimum value. I do not understand what you want to achieve with `x_grid`. Maybe if u tell us a bit more about why you need it, then it would be easier.

Comment: Actually that too got resolved it was actually indp.min() and indp.max() but it later gave an error on ```plt.scatter(indp,dep,color='red')``` also I checked shapes of indp = (18,5) and dep= (18,)

Answer (score 0):

use - np.arange(np.min(indp),np.max(indp),0.1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).